# Unity Hololens 2 Anchor persistant between sessions without cloud connexion

Tags: unity-game-engine, anchor, augmented-reality, hololens

I am building an app on Unity 2020.3.19 version / MRTK 2.7.
I want to save localy the position of an object and to reload it on another session without any wifi connexion.
I have been locking for solutions but WSA obsolete/ qrcode for positioning microsoft solution crashing ...
How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that you use World Locking Tools for all your hologram positioning needs. To persist spatial coordinate systems, we can enable AutoSave & AutoLoad on the World Locking Tools Manager, World Locking Tools will restore Unity's coordinate system relative to the physical world across sessions on the HoloLens family of devices. For more information please see: [World locking and spatial anchors in Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/spatial-anchors-in-unity?tabs=worldanchor)